# Calculating non-duplicates

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have below data in three columns.

```
A        B           C
07002    72J217.4    72J217
07002    72J229.5    72J129
07002    72J229.6    72J129
07002    72J229.7    72J129
07006    61E001.5    61E001
07006    61E001.6    61E001
07006    61E001.7    61E001
07006    61E002.1    61E002
07006    61E002.2    61E002
07006    61E003.3    61E003
```

I need a formula to give result as below:

In a cell I will enter one of the values in col A "07002" and next cell should show the count of as 2 (i.e. unique values 72J217 & 72J129 excluding duplicates in range Col C), and if I enter "07006", then it should show count as 3 (i.e. 61E001,61E002 and 61E003).

How can I achieve this with a formula?

Answer (score 0):

If a value eg 07006 is in 'E1', this will give the correct result:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(($A$1:$A$10=E1)/(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10,E1,$C$1:$C$10,$C$1:$C$10)),0))
```

if entered as an array formula (type ctrl+shift+enter instead of just enter after typing the formula).